# Docker not syncing hosts folder (Windows)

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

When I share a folder between my host and my containers, my files edited in Sublime are not syncing inside the containers.

I'm using Docker version 1.13.0, build 49bf474 and I tried many fixes that some issues on github told me to do, but none of them worked for me.

I'm sharing my C/ driver with docker host, configuring my compose like this:

uwsgi:
    build: .
    links:
      - postgres
    command: ./uwsgi.sh
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - /static
      - /data/media:/media
      - ./api:/app

My volume ./api:/app works, but when i change something, its not reflects on the container and I can't use for development.

Here is my inspect for this container: (Mounts/Volumes)

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/C/Users/tif/projetos/my/jl.api/api",
            "Destination": "/app",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        },
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/data/media",
            "Destination": "/media",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        },
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "b931d6d30c2b8e1bcdc2a20d5e6d2c27dd515c5041d2ea64ca01b5dc08047879",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/b931d6d30c2b8e1bcdc2a20d5e6d2c27dd515c5041d2ea64ca01b5dc08047879/_data",
            "Destination": "/static",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
    "Volumes": {
            "/app": {},
            "/media": {},
            "/static": {}
        },
```

This things I have already tried:

- atomic_save: false (Sublime)
- nginx.conf with sendfile off;

Someone have experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I could see that I was using uWsgi for development environment, and I couldn't get my app reloading without the py-autoreload.

All i had to get done was start my uwsgi setting the py-autoreload to 2 and my app started to reloads.

I'm starting this command on docker now:

```
"/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --socket :5000 --wsgi-file ......... --py-autoreload 2
```

Reading this could be useful if you are experiencing this issue: http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2014/03/30/uwsgi-python-reload.html